# How to return pointer to `GlobalData`?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

I'm writing a pure C FFI layer to XLA and want to return a pointer to `GlobalData`, as produced by `xla::LocalClient.TransferToServer(...)`. I've tried to create a new `GlobalData` on the free store and, since the comments in the source code say

```
  // Unregisters the wrapped handle, which causes the service to
  // deallocate the associated data.
  ~GlobalData();
```

I also release the handle of the stack copy, as

```
xla::GlobalData* fn(xla::LocalClient* client, xla::Literal literal) {
  std::unique_ptr<xla::GlobalData> global_data =
    client.TransferToServer(literal).ConsumeValueOrDie();

  xla::GlobalData* global_data_non_stack =
    new xla::GlobalData(client.stub(), global_data->handle());
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<xla::GlobalData>> to_release;
  to_release.push_back(std::move(global_data));
  xla::GlobalData::Release(std::move(to_release));

  return global_data_non_stack;
}
```

but it's not working. It appears to still be deallocating the handle so when I `client.ExecuteAndTransfer(...)` I see

```
2022-01-09 13:42:23.862961: F tensorflow/core/platform/statusor.cc:33] Attempting to fetch value instead of handling error Invalid argument: global data handle 1 was previously deallocated, failed to resolve allocation for parameter 0
```

I've also tried `client.Unregister(*global_data)` which doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure about this, but if I use `.release()` instead of `.get()`, the `std::unique_ptr<xla::GlobalData>` loses ownership of the `GlobalData` and I can safely return the resulting pointer knowing nothing is going to automatically free the memory it points to. There's no need to create a new `GlobalData` instance.